# Fetch value of one2many treeview in a simple treeview on another model

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

```
<field name="flock_visit_tree" string="Flock Details">
  <tree string="your string" create="true" delete="true" editable="top">

  <field name="farm_visit"/>
  <field name="visit_age_day"/>
  <field name="visit_age_week"/>
  <field name="visit_body_weight"/>
  <field name="visit_mortality"/>
  <field name="visit_feed_detail" string="Feed Detail"/>

  </tree>
</field>
```

I need this treeview in a simple tree view on another model and want to fetch data automatically not to use many2many field.

Comment: Please edit your question and add: 1. Your code/your attempts 2. Your input, current output and expected output

Comment: sir i need to add a clone of one2many treeview i do not have any output or code. just same treeview on other model.

Comment: in short i need to fetch a treeview on other model with all values.....

Answer (score 0):

if you want that the field one2many to behave like the many2many field  when you click additem in o2m field you create a record directly but in m2m you get a select popup shown if you want this the in the field o2m put `<field name="field_name" widget="many2many"  options="{'not_delete':true}"/>` not delete because when you delete record in one2many it deletes it from the other model not delete privent that from happening if this not what you want sorry ^^ but i think this information will help you as it help me in some cases like this